# Android Circular Reveal transition for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

Hi I wonder if exits some way to implement a circular reveal transition to replace my fragments or some other alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i found a tutorial about it.
https://medium.com/@gabornovak/circular-reveal-animation-between-fragments-d8ed9011aec

Hope this helps!